# How to do equivalent of yarn link for Heroku App?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, yarn-v2

Setup: I've a react app B on my laptop and B depends on a package A that I also developed locally. I am using `yarn link` for this dependency and it works fine.

Now when I try to deploy B to heroku I realized it's not clear how I could deploy A as well so that Heroku knows about it. I could make A a git submodule of B and push it all at once, but how do I perform the yarn link?

Comment: I don't know much about this stack so I'm not posting an answer, but even if this is possible you probably shouldn't do it. Just publish the package. `yarn link` isn't meant for production: "Symlink a package folder during development. For development, a package can be linked into another project. This is often useful to test out new features or when trying to debug an issue in a package that manifests itself in another project."

Comment: @Chris Thanks! In my case publishing it is a bit tricky since this package is my modification of a public package. What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: There are a few options. If your change would benefit the upstream project, I suggest trying to contribute it. It's always nice if you can hand off maintenance to somebody else, plus you won't have to worry about porting your change to newer versions or using an old version that doesn't get bugfixes and new features. If that's not an option you could host it publicly with a different name (e.g. `library-featureX-fork`) or [privately](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=yarn+private+package).